# Judiciously trying to scrape but can't due to complex headers

Tags: web-scraping, https, python-requests

I am trying to scrape some links but cant. I used developer tool to see the request headers and here it is:

```
headers = {
      'authority': 'www.some-website.com',
      'method': 'GET',
      'path': '/kapi/secure/search-api?query=cholera&page=1',
      'scheme': 'https',
      'accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
      'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
      'accept-language': 'en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8',
      'client_id': 'ffoesvm90e-6323-4asdac-a349-e78acdd2de60',
      'cookie': 'gtinfo="ct":"Pune","c":null,"cc":null,"st":"MH","sc":null,"z":"411006","tPX7NGuJNduSQ=',
      'enc_data': 'yeJuSFb2zdRB3EB5xBXdOdfdJSbCkOsvoOowRSK2AgY=',
      'if-modified-since': 'Thu, 07 Feb 2024 13:52:33 GMT',
      'if-none-match': 'W/"48b2-B0FEMq5XbvUKqxfj4LwSdKJCVWI"',
      'referer': f'https://www.some-website.com/search?query=cholera',
      'sec-ch-ua': '" Not A;Brand";v="99", "Chromium";v="102", "Google Chrome";v="102"',
      'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
      'sec-ch-ua-platform': '"Linux"',
      'sec-fetch-dest': 'empty',
      'sec-fetch-mode': 'cors',
      'sec-fetch-site': 'same-origin',
      'timestamp': '1707410436',
      'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/102.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'
      }
```

But copying these headers and sending using requests in Python, doesn't work after sometime. It works for couple of minutes only. Is it because of changing 'enc_data' and other attributes of the headers?
What to do to get proper response from the website?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tokens and ID are frequently used by websites for a variety of reasons, such as stopping bot activity and api abuse.

Usually, these dynamic strings or tokens come from two sources:

**1. It is generated in the website using javascript**

- Use Browser Sources tab to search through the javascript to find where it is generated.
- Code will be minified so, it is not obvious.
- A good starting point is to find the initiator for the request in network and follow it.
- Once you found how it is generated, try to replicate the same to get your token

**2. It is from response of a previous request. Either as a cookie, response header, body etc.,**

- The string could be from a previous response.
- Use preserve_log option in network tab and search the string and find where it was seen first
- If you find it, you can make that request first, fetch the string and use it before making the main request.

It could also be any other approach or a combination of the first two.
the header **`enc_data`** could mean **`encrypted data`**.
Unfortunately, without knowing the exact domain and what you're looking for, I cant help much further.

If you are ok with moving to other process, choose a Javascript rendering library / tool like selenium or puppeteer and leave the Javascript execution to it and you can get the response.
But it has its own trade off, issues and process.

Remember,

1. Always refer to robots.txt to determine what is and is not permitted to scrape.
2. Limiting rates is one of the application for these tokens. Take care not to ask for too much at once.
3. Tokens are used by websites to stop service abuse.

Answer (score 0):

you may try httpx that support http2, many websites block http1 requests.